# List static member with no value in a Protocol class

Tags: python

This example only prints `STATIC_MEMBER_1`. It does not list `STATIC_MEMBER_2`. I'd like a way to list both of them.

```
class Foo(Protocol):
    MY_STATIC_MEMBER_1: int = 42
    MY_STATIC_MEMBER_2: int

print(dir(Foo))
```

I've tried using `inspect` and `__mro__` but I cannot get it to list `STATIC_MEMBER_2`.

Comment: `Foo` doesn't have an attribute named `MY_STATIC_MEMBER_2`, only an entry in its `__annotations__` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars` built-in function does what you need I guess
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars
Btw. your member is not static, it's a class variable, kinda the same...but different in detail

```
vars(Foo)

mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', '__annotations__': {'MY_STATIC_MEMBER_1': <class 'int'>, 'MY_STATIC_MEMBER_2': <class 'int'>}, 'MY_STATIC_MEMBER_1': 42, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__parameters__': (), '_is_protocol': True, '__subclasshook__': <function Protocol.__init_subclass__.<locals>._proto_hook at 0x7f7db7b9f1a0>, '__init__': <function _no_init_or_replace_init at 0x7f7db77dd4e0>, '__abstractmethods__': frozenset(), '_abc_impl': <_abc._abc_data object at 0x7f7db77ed4c0>})
```

Comment: Ah vars! Yes class variable, I was thinking C++ terminology. Great thanks!